# Get data from a JSON file

Tags: objective-c, json

I created an App with a TableView and I want to get Data from my Server of a .json file. It works very good with the iTunes Top Albums json file but if I use mine there is nothing displayed no Data or Error. Hope you can help me.
This is my Code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Fail with Error");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *allDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *arrayOfItems = [allDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfItems) {
        NSString *name = [diction objectForKey:@"Name2"];

        [self.objects addObject:name];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *objectPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"objects1"];
        [self.objects writeToFile:objectPath atomically:YES];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)refreshing
{
    [_objects removeAllObjects];
    [_tableBar reloadData];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nefkom.net/rekker/test.json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

And this is my JSON file:

```
{ identifier: "AutoID", items:[ 
{ AutoID: 9,"Name":"Testfirma12aaaa Antonaaa","Name2":"Götz Hermann","Street":"Abenbergerstr.5","Postcode":"99084","City":"Erfurt","Phone":"09112 931040"}
,{ AutoID: 50302,"Name":"Klinikum St. Marien Amberg Stabsstelle Katastrophenschutz","Name2":"Bigalke Marc","Street":"Mariahilfbergweg 7","Postcode":"92224","City":"Amberg","Phone":""}
,{ AutoID: 50290,"Name":"Rüdiger Schnick Industrieberatung","Name2":"Schnick  Rüdiger","Street":"Kinzigweg 23","Postcode":"42579","City":"Heiligenhaus","Phone":"02056 / 9320-0"}
,{ AutoID: 50308,"Name":"VEGS GmbH & Co. KG","Name2":"Verband Europäischer Gutachter & Sachverständiger","Street":"Erlanger Str. 2","Postcode":"","City":"","Phone":"49 (0) 921 210767-1"}
,{ AutoID: 50299,"Name":"Kimont","Name2":"534/4 -Mobiler Medizinischer Dienst-","Street":"","Postcode":"","City":"","Phone":""}
,{ AutoID: 6275,"Name":"A+H Meyer","Name2":"","Street":"Flottenstraße 60","Postcode":"13407","City":"Berlin","Phone":"030 414 7800"}
,{ AutoID: 50306,"Name":"Versicherungskammer Bayern","Name2":"","Street":"Limbacher Str. 17","Postcode":"","City":"","Phone":""}
,{ AutoID: 50304,"Name":"Tdb Software Service GmbH ","Name2":"Götz Hermann","Street":"Abenberger Str. 5","Postcode":"","City":"","Phone":"09122 93103"}
,{ AutoID: 50301,"Name":"","Name2":"","Street":"","Postcode":"","City":"","Phone":""}
,{ AutoID: 1,"Name":"DB Schenker Rail Deutschland AG Anforderungsmanagement Angebotsplanung (","Name2":"Mayer Herbert","Street":"Rheinstraße 2a","Postcode":"91126","City":"Schwabach","Phone":""}
,{ AutoID: 82,"Name":"Rainer Ockens Gabelstaplerhandel GmbH","Name2":"Ockens Rainer","Street":"Theodorstr. 41 Z","Postcode":"22761","City":"Hamburg","Phone":"040/8993302"}
,{ AutoID: 3409,"Name":"Friedrich A. Krusejun.Logistics Gmbh und Co.KG ","Name2":"Emmerrich Dirk","Street":"Chemipark Leverkusen/ Gebäude B9","Postcode":"51368","City":"Leverkusen","Phone":"0214 30 23535"}
,{ AutoID: 137,"Name":"Budny Transportgeräte-Service","Name2":"","Street":"Brunnenstr. 4","Postcode":"04519","City":"Rackwitz","Phone":"034294/76764"}
,{ AutoID: 271,"Name":"KSPE Kalksandstein-Planelemente GmbH & Co.KG ","Name2":"Regenet ","Street":"Zum Vogelsberg 12","Postcode":"45721","City":"Haltern","Phone":"02364-9632-0"}
]}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this?

Comment: Have you fed your "JSON" through an online JSON verifier?  (Hint, it's not valid JSON.  But you would know this if you had made use of the error parm on JSONObjectWithData.)

Comment: Another hint:  There is a glaring error in every line of your JSON file.

Comment: (Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax. It takes only 5-10 minutes to absorb.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should try:

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *allDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:&jsonError];

if ( jsonError ) {
    NSLog( @"JSON error: %@", jsonError.description );
}
```

You don't pass an error object, you should since investigating the error can help point you to the error.

Comment: And whatever "tutorial" you copied that style of coding from, don't use it again.  Any "tutorial" that doesn't tell you to examine the error code should not be trusted.

Comment: @HotLicks Who is this directed at?

Comment: The OP. For some reason I can't "@" him.